# Is there a simple man's perspective of Pauli’s exclusion principle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, fermions, pauli-exclusion-principle, spin-statistics

I've been pondering over a questions from a while. Please forgive me if I am being too naive.

We all know that because of Pauli's exclusion principle no two electrons can populate one state. This prevents the electrons from being collapsed into nucleus, as explained [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/54674/i-dont-understand-the-relationship-between-electron-indistinguishability-and-th) from the anti-symmetric nature of their wave functions, also as explained in a comment by [ACuriousMind](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/50583/acuriousmind). Is there any simple man perspective (classical analogue/picture) why there should be any such principle in the first place?

Comment: What do you mean "how does it know"? Why does it need to "know"? It's an electron, not a conscious being. And there is no simple explanation of the Pauli exclusion principle, its actual formulation and derivation is the [spin-statistic theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin%E2%80%93statistics_theorem). Furthermore, your two questions appear rather unrelated, please ask only one question per post.

Comment: Thanks for quick comment. I have read the article however I have not understood it much except for the fact that in order to be Lorentz invariant the wavefunction of the 1/2 integer spin particles should be antisymmetric but still wondering why. Sorry for posting two seemingly  uncorrelated questions, I was just wondering about excitation and de-excitation of atoms

Comment: I suppose that to try and give a classical model, people would have to understand Quantum Mechanics, but according to Feynman "I think I can safely say that nobody understands quantum mechanics" (Richard Feynman, in The Feynman Lectures on Physics, vol III, p. 18-9 (1965)
)

Comment: I would take this question answered as "there is no classical analogue of Pauli's exclusion principle".

Comment: yes, no calogue because it is due to angular momentum quantization (spin)  and not only. The Pauli exclusion models the data.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_exclusion_principle#History

Comment: @hsinghal : it's because the electron is a "spinor". It's like _two waves can run over one another but two whirlpools cannot overlap_.